# Failed to initialize PushKit device token

Tags: ios, react-native, twilio, react-native-call-keep

I have been trying to integrate [twilio-voice-react-native](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-voice-react-native) with react-native-call-keep to make outgoing calls through the app. It is working fine with the below code on Android but giving `Failed to initialize PushKit device token` on iOS.

```
  const voice = new Voice();

  const initializeCallKeep = async () => {
    try {
      RNCallKeep.setup({
        ios: {
          appName: "App Name",
        },
        android: {
          alertTitle: "Permissions required",
          alertDescription:
            "This application needs to access your phone accounts",
          cancelButton: "Cancel",
          additionalPermissions: [],
          okButton: "ok",
        },
      });
      RNCallKeep.setAvailable(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("initializeCallKeep error>>>>>", err);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    initializeCallKeep();
  }, []);

const callAction = async () => {
     const token = await getAccessToken();
     await voice.register(token);
     const twiMLParams = {
        params: {
          guestName: firstName + " " + lastName,
        },
      };
      const callUUID = getGUID();
      const call = await voice.connect(token, twiMLParams);
      RNCallKeep.startCall(callUUID, "", phoneNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and going through multiple articles for some time, I was able to find a solution to fix the iOS issue.

You need to first call `await voice.initializePushRegistry();` before doing `voice.register();`.

Here's the updated code:

```
const callAction = async () => {
   await voice.initializePushRegistry();
   const token = await getAccessToken();
      await voice.register(token);
      const twiMLParams = {
        params: {
          guestName: firstName + " " + lastName,
        },
      };
      const callUUID = getGUID();
      const call = await voice.connect(token, twiMLParams);
      RNCallKeep.startCall(callUUID, "App name", phoneNumber);
 }
```

For more - https://github.com/twilio/twilio-voice-react-native/blob/main/docs/applications-own-pushkit-handler.md